# why is my cloudfront caching not working?

Tags: caching, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

Okay, so I noticed my Cloudfront isn't caching when I ran Google Page Tools and it told me that my images had no expiration set. I use Amazon S3 through Cloudfront. There's no headers set on S3 because I have hundreds of folders and thousands of image files with new ones uploaded every hour.

I went to my Cloudfront console, to Behaviours, edited the only one there and set:

```
Minimum TTL: 86400
Maximum TTL: 31536000
Default TTL: 86400
```

And I checked the 'Customize' option for 'Object Caching'. I then went to invalidate and invalidated all my objects (*). I waited until it was done, but my headers when requesting a file still shows:

```
Age:8
Connection:keep-alive
Date:Mon, 07 Dec 2015 00:44:39 GMT
ETag:"429d87a5fd35288d207635d2a853fa0b"
Server:AmazonS3
Via:1.1 (my-ID-here).cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
X-Amz-Cf-Id:RxHlfhhnrSk9YwIqpFySnPVrscndnknZ9RKlIryXCLwh4RCK9vK6Vw==
X-Cache:Hit from cloudfront
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The response headers `X-Cache: Hit from cloudfront` and `Age: 8` show that CloudFront *is* caching content for you.  What makes you think it isn't?  You should he setting `Cache-Control:` headers on objects when you upload them to S3 but that's a secondary issue.

Answer (score 0):

Was this under "Leverage browser caching" or a similar section of Page Tools?

If under 'Leverage Browser Caching', - this doesn't mean the files aren't being cached, but it means that the requested files aren't requesting end user browsers to cache them - for instance using the 'Cache-Control' or 'Expires' headers. CloudFront, unless configured otherwise, caches files from S3 -- so the absence of these headers doesn't affect *Cloudfront's* caching.

You can manually add these in S3 for the individual objects. 
Some more info can be found in the [CloudFront documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/Expiration.html#ExpirationDownloadDist)